# Using react-redux-firebase to comsume cloud functions - React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-functions, react-redux-firebase

I'm new to React JS. I'm trying to develop one simple web page which renders data from cloud firestore. And I'm using `react-redux-firebase` to fetch the data. It is working fine. Now I want the data to be fetched from cloud functions. I have deployed the cloud functions successfully. And I can even fetch the data from cloud functions using `axios`. But I want to use `react-redux-firebase`. I searched a lot and couldn't find a single example. Please help me.

```
const firebase = getFirebase();

    var animals = firebase
        .functions()
        .httpsCallable("getAllAnimals");
    animals()
        .then(result => {
            console.log("result ------------- ", result)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('errorrrrrrrr ' + error)
        );
```

Using this, I'm getting the below error.

```
errorrrrrrrr Error: Response is missing data field.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the callable function that you intended to invoke.  Note that your client client is specifically trying to invoke a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), and it should be defined as such in on the backend.

Comment: I don't think `react-redux-firebase` is meant to replace a requests library like Axios o the Fetch API, and in the end your Cloud Function is an HTTP endpoint. Have you checked if it works using Axios? Also could you share both the functions code and the snippet tha makes the request in the react component? (now the function code seems incomplete)

Comment: @Happy-Monad, Thank you. Using Axios I'm able to fetch the data. But I wanted to centralize my data at one point. Thats y I wanted to go with react-redux-firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I think two different things are mixed up here, the library `react-reduc-firebase` and centralizing state.

As you said in the comments you're able to query the HTTP Cloud function with a request library such as Axios though I understand you want to also query the Cloud Function through the `react-redux-firebase`. However the library is not intended for querying arbitrary HTTP endpoints, such as this function or any other HTTP reachable API. Instead the library is meant to be a comfortable and out-of-the-box interface to seamlessly interact with products that have their own JS client libraries and API which would otherwise require you to write all the glue code yourself. The reason why you cannot find Cloud Functions in the Github's [feature list](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase#features) it's probably because there is no special treatment needed to reach them, thus no interface layer is provided.

Separately, I understand you want to centralize your data in the spirit of a Redux (Flux) application architecture. IMO the fact that you use both Axios and Firestore does not conflict with the principle of centralized state management which is agnostic about how data is obtained as long as it's changes and management align with Redux [core principles](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles). It makes sense that not all your information is accessible with a single procedure when each database has their specifics quircks.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is trying to use cloud functions with `react-redux-firebase`, it is possible if configured possibly.

In your main app's `index.js` file, where you configure firebase for the `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider`, be sure to also import `firebase/functions`.

```
// src/index.js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/functions';
```

This will allow you to use `firebase.functions()` in conjunction with the `useFirebase()` hook.